# Convert hand written data log to excel

Tags: ocr

I have to enter loads of hand written data into excel and I was wondering if there is an easier way of doing it than typing all the data into the excel manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Excel doesn't run on Ubuntu. Please clarify how your question is related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `ocrfeeder` or `gimagereader` to convert handwritting to editable text. Then you will be able to Copy&Paste it to excel.

Both this programs need a lot of tweaking, I recommend reading documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Thanx! gimagereader is a good GUI for tesseract, you can also multiple select parts of an image or pdf to convert, i.e by columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to scan the files with a scanner, you can use ABBYY Screenshot Reader (you can find it via torrent...hmmm I mean buy it) which works with the latest wine without any libraries needed. It's the only tool that ever worked for me. You will still have to copy and paste all the info to excel though, I don't know any program which is able to understand hand written tables (if that's the case).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)